# Magento simple products not visible individually still show up

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I have a Magento website in which all of the configurable products are set to **Catalog, Search** and the child products are set to **Not visible Individually**. However, if I search the website I seem to be able to find the child products and even buy them. What am I missing here? I

Comment: Rebuild the indexes. If that does not help, make sure that the product visibility is set to `Not visible individually` at store view level, not at global level.

Comment: Can you tell me your process of creating configurable products?...If you followed this way...it doesn't show child products http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-configurable.html

Comment: Try changing the scope when editing the product.  It is possible that the visibility is being overridden by settings at the website/store level.

Comment: Ok... it seems that this is the case:  in Magento 1.x, for some reason, all configurable products are set to "Catalog, Search" while all Simple products are always set to "Not Visible Individually" and .... that's just how it works. Is this the case ?